# How to enable memory usage diagnostic for locally published site in vs2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, diagnostics

When I debug my WebApp project in VS2015 the memory diagnostic view is unavailable even though the cpu view is working. The project is built and published in to a separate directory over a vanilla Sitecore7 CMS install.

If I just run the app the memory diagnostic shows, however the app doesn't actually work because it requires publishing. If I publish the app out, debugging and CPU diagnostic work but memory diagnostic isn't available (see image). How can I make it work?

It's a WebApp project running under dotnet 4.6.2.

**Summary:** If I debug a site which is locally published I get CPU usage diagnostic, but not memory diagnostic. How do I get memory diagnostic to work?

[image: memory diagnosic unavailable]

Comment: this may be helpful initially http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: Is the TOOLS, Options, Debugging, Managed or Native Compatibility mode enabled?  If so, uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the diagnostic tools windows, click Memory Usage and enable snapshots. That should work.

If not try unchecking CPU usage and display that. You can always just use task manager :)